# NoMethodError: undefined method `equity='

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got an error like following, with $ bundle exec rake db:seed.
I'm using rails 3.2.2, and mysql. Any other model is not defined.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `equity=' for #<Company:0x007fd1cdb5b2a0>
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-3.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:148:in `method_missing'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/db/seeds.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/codes/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:309:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My db/seed.rb is like:

```
@company = Company.new
@company.ticker = "1111"
@company.name = "Cheese Company"
@company.year = "2015"
@company.fixed_asset = 30000
@company.current_asset = 20000
@company.equity = 35000
@company.long_term_liabilities = 8000
@company.short_term_liabilities = 7000
@company.revenue = 30000
@company.operating_income = 15000
@company.ibit = 10000
@company.net_income = 3500
@company.operation_cashflow = 5800
@company.financing_cashflow = 5500
@company.investment_cashflow = 2000
@company.save
```

and model definition is:

```
$ cat app/models/company.rb 
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
end

$ cat db/migrate/20160131155124_create_companies.rb 
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :ticker
      t.string :name
      t.string :year
      t.decimal :fixed_asset
      t.decimal :current_asset
      t.decimal :long_term_liabilities
      t.decimal :short_term_liabilities
      t.decimal :revenue
      t.decimal :operating_income
      t.decimal :ibit
      t.decimal :net_income
      t.decimal :operation_cashflow
      t.decimal :financing_cashflow
      t.decimal :investment_cashflow
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any other model than 'Company' is not defined yet.
Any help welcome, thanks a lot.

Comment: do you see `equity` in your `create_companies` migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you migration add equity column also

```
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :ticker
      t.string :name
      t.string :year
      t.decimal :fixed_asset
      t.decimal :current_asset
      t.decimal :long_term_liabilities
      t.decimal :short_term_liabilities
      t.decimal :revenue
      t.decimal :operating_income
      t.decimal :ibit
      t.decimal :net_income
      t.decimal :operation_cashflow
      t.decimal :financing_cashflow
      t.decimal :investment_cashflow
      t.decimal :equity
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```